# Does reading proprietary artwork in the source code violate GPLv3 license?

Tags: gpl, gpl-3

Just out of curiosity, if I make a GPLv3 software that have source code that tell the program to read a file that is a proprietary artwork, but this artwork is not included in my project, does that violate GPLv3 license?

For example, I made a game project that look like this:

folder:My Game
file:main.py

```
# Copyright (C) 2023 My Name
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later

import os

if os.path.isfile("proprietary_artwork_package/game_conversation.txt"):
    print("Thank you for buying the artwork package! Enjoy!")
    f = open("proprietary_artwork_package/game_conversation.txt")
    print(f.read())
    f.close()
else:
    print(
        "Please buy the artwork of my game at https://www.some-membership-platform.com/my-support-page.html, extract it at the game folder to get the full gaming experience!"
    )
print("\n\nThe end.\n\n\nCredit:\n\tAAA\n\tBBB\n\tCCC\n")
print("GPLv3 License stuff.")
```

file: license.txt

```
<content of GPLv3 license>
```

Does this game project violate GPLv3 license?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's fine.

Artwork and code are different things, and they can exist and be distributed independently.

The open source version of a number of games are example of these kind of behaviour (e.g. [OpenTTD](https://www.openttd.org/), [OpenDune](https://github.com/OpenDUNE/OpenDUNE), [CorsixTH](https://corsixth.com/), etc) as are the converse relation with free and sometimes open source fan modpacks for proprietary games.

Usually the graphics need to be supplied in a well-defined format to be interpreted correctly by the programme (and which has to be documented to at least some degree) and thus there exists a public API by which they communicate with (or are 'digested' by) the programme.